# How to get just information in a specific node in msinfo32.exe

Tags: command-line

I am have been trying to get a text file that has only problem devices node in it, but the following syntax does not do that:

msinfo32 /report test.txt /category +componentsproblemdevices

That command still shows everything.

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using?

Answer (score 2):

`Category` is not an MSInfo32 option in versions of Windows newer than XP.

From [How to use System Information (MSINFO32) command-line tool switches](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/300887):

> • Some command-line switches available for Windows XP are no longer supported in Windows Vista or in Windows 7.

There are only three valid MSInfo32 command-line switches in Windows Vista+:

> Command options that are supported in Windows 7, Windows Vista and Windows XP
>
> /nfo {Path}  Saves the exported file as an .nfo file. If the file name
>   that is specified in Path does not end in .nfo, an .nfo file name
>   extension will be appended to the file name.
>
> /report {Path}  Saves the file that is specified in Path in the .txt
>   format. The file name will be saved exactly as it appears in path. The
>   .txt file name extension will not be appended to the file unless it is
>   specified in Path.
>
> /computer {ComputerName}  Starts System Information for the specified
>   remote computer.  Note When you connect to a remote computer, you must
>   have appropriate permissions to access WMI on the remote computer.